# One of three PictureBoxes does not update

Tags: c#, winforms

**Background:**

My program is live video winform application. I have three `PictureBox` on my form. Those picture boxes are automatically resized according to their parent form size. A thread in my program updates those picture box with three 2048x2048 images from 30 fps camera using safe `Invoke` method.

**Problem:**

When the form is small enough, all three pictureboxes display fine although the problematic picture box is little slower than the others. But if the form gets bigger, just one of picture boxes not updated while the other two are updated well. FYI, those pictures are pushed into the pixture boxes at the same time. It may sound silly but the problamatic picture box looks defective

**Question:**

I would like to understand why this symptom occurs - Same-size picture boxes got same size of images at the same time but only one of them is not updated. Is this video card problem?  Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: I'd try swapping the box names around - does the problem follow the name (/variable) or does it follow order of creation? Might give you a clue where to look.

Comment: Can you paste the code?, I guess you are using form resizing events?

Comment: @CarlosLande no I am not using form resizing. I just use TableLayoutPanel and Anchor to resize pictureboxes as form resizes.

Comment: It can sound stupid, but Can you try with another Image resource to be sure the problem is not in the image itself?

Comment: @CarlosLande :-) I've already tried with same image and same images with clone. The same result.I believe it's windows form. It seems like UI becomes too busy. Maybe I need to think about UI thread??

Comment: Try with simple control.Refresh() and If this doesn't work I would try updating the controls in other thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

As I think this is a problem with form refresh, I created a thread to periodically refresh my form. And I think the non-update problem is resolved.

```
    private void MyForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Thread thread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            while (!m_bFormClose)
            {
                this.SafeInvoke(Refresh);
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        });
        thread.Start();
    }
```

I guess I can do this with timer but I feel more safe with thread. If you have a better way, please comment or answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to using c# open source ispy software http://www.ispyconnect.com/